# Dynamic content in User Control [Metro app, xaml]

Tags: xaml, dynamic, user-controls, microsoft-metro

I'm approaching to Metro App development in this days, so please be gentle.

I have created a User Control - some buttons and textblocks- that is loaded in every page of my app. I want the texblocks to change dynamically depending on the page selected: for example one of the texblocks of the user control is the page title. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you can go for a simple code by finding the children of the usercontrol you are adding.

xaml code

```
xmlns:newPage="using:TestApp"
```

add the page like this in say mainpage.xaml:

```
<newPage:TestPage x:Name="pageNew"></newPage:TestPage>
```

then from code behind of the mainpage ie mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public mainpage(){
```

InitializeComponent();
var newPageContent = pageNew.Content; //here content will give u the immidiete children of usercntrl
}

Now you can type cast like 
`(Grid)newPageContent = pageNew.content;
var TextBlockFirst = newPageContent.children[0];`

and so on :) please check if the suggestion is helpful :)